# Using Peerjs in android with Webview but it requires touch to update video

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webrtc, peerjs

I'm using peerjs to make video calls, but I notice that It needs to keep tapping on the screen to update the video on webview. also, it's not auto-playing video until I touch it, after touching on screen I can see an updated frame but again it looks like feezed.

I have setup webview code as below,

```
 private fun setupWebView() {

        binding.webView.webChromeClient = object: WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest?) {
                request?.grant(request.resources)
            }
        }
        binding.webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        binding.webView.settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
        binding.webView.addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface(this), "Android")

        binding.webView.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                initializePeer()
            }
        }

        loadWebApp()
    }

    private fun loadWebApp() {
        val filePath = "file:///android_asset/peerjs/call.html"
        binding.webView.loadUrl(filePath)
    }
```

Please help on this

Comment: This has been reported as a bug to Chromium a while ago: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1401352

Comment: Thanks @PhilippHancke, is this issue still not fixed?

Comment: So far it is still in the "untriaged" state which means nobody who could fix it has taken a look at what the actual issue is.